# How does Mutex scope work

Tags: c, mutex

How does mutex scope work exactly.

If I want 3 mutexes for different things and place them as so

```
static pthread_mutex_t watchdogMutex = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;
static pthread_cond_t watchdogCond = PTHREAD_COND_INITIALIZER;
int waitingForGpsSetupThread = 1;

static pthread_mutex_t gpsRunningMutex = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;
int gpsRunning = 0;

static pthread_mutex_t indoorNavigationRunningMutex = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;
int indoorSystemRunning = 0;
```

Are the variables defined within the scope of the first above mutex declaration or how does it work?

Comment: "Are the variables defined within the scope..." Sorry, I don't understand the question. Can you rephrase it? Anyway, there's no such concept as "mutex scope".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As written, the three mutexes are all in the same scope.  There are no blocks marked by '{...}' to indicate otherwise.  The same would be true if the types were all `int`.  From that point of view, a mutex is no different from any other type.

At the point of use, you would do something like:

```
pthread_mutex_lock(&watchdogMutex);

...operations protected by the watchdog mutex...

pthread_mutex_unlock(&watchdogMutex);
```

The bit in the middle could be said to be the scope in which the mutex is locked.  It would be a very bad idea to have a `return` statement in the middle of those operations - unless the mutex was also unlocked before returning.

See the [POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/pthread_mutex_lock.html) definitions.

Comment: Thanks. what is the best way to use mutexes and the variables mentioned above in another module?

Comment: @Helium3: given that the mutexes are all static, they cannot be used directly from another module.  Something from within the current module would have to provide access to them - either a function returning a pointer to a mutex, or a function that locks the mutex (and presumably another that unlocks it).  You would be best off doing the relevant access from within the module; the protected variables should have the same scope as the mutexes.  Exposing the 'protected' variable but not the protection means that the variable can be abused, which the mutex is meant to prevent.

Answer (score 2):

These are just C variables. It doesn't matter in what order you declare them. What matters is in what order you try to acquire/lock the mutexes if you want to hold them at the same time (as in "always acquire resources in the same order" mantra).

#### Edit 0:

Looks like you can use some introductory threads material:

- [POSIX Threads Programming](https://computing.llnl.gov/tutorials/pthreads/)
- [Pthreads Tutorial](http://www.cs.nmsu.edu/~jcook/Tools/pthreads/pthreads.html)

I still remember how to google ... :)

Comment: So, When reading or writing, they should be called in the same order? What is the point of many mutexes? Will one be enough for all variables as long as it is called only once per code block during read/write?

Comment: @Helium3: you use a separate mutex to protect a variable or group of variables from simultaneous access by multiple threads.  You get to choose the granularity of locking - it is a design decision.  Having three mutexes should mean there are (at least) three separate resources to protect from concurrent usage.  As far as possible (which may not be very far), avoid holding more than one mutex at a time.  When you must hold several, ensure you do not end up with a deadlock.

Comment: So one mutex per variable/resource? What if a mutex is locked, 2 variables are written or read in the order they were declared and then the mutex is UNlocked again? Another question is, what if a thread has locked a mutex and is writing , while another thread is trying to lock it to read?

Comment: @Helium3: your comment says 'mutex is locked; then locked again'?  You can't/shouldn't do that - or I don't understand what you are asking.  If a thread has the mutex lock, it has mutually exclusive access to the variables - and can write; the other thread will have to wait for its turn with the mutex, and when it gets the mutex, can read the variables safely.   (Always hold the mutex for as short a time as possible, to minimize the loss of concurrency.)

Comment: It was a typo, I changed it to unlocked.Thanks for explaining, so one mutex per variable helps maintain concurrency?

Comment: @Nikolai: I have read it before. didnt cover what I needed to know.